# unimportant features impact on model's performance

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, xgboost

Using XGBoost and RandomForests, do unimportant features (according to the `feature_importances_` attribute) hurt the model's performance?

Do I need to carefully select highly correlated ***and*** import features? Or do I throw everything in and hope that it can correctly add some information on the target variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unimportant features can hurt the model's performance. This happens in my experience in a few ways:

1. Efficiency - they make the fitting process slower. Particularly if you're one-hot encoding categorical features, and end up with a large and useless sparse matrix. If these reductions in efficiency force you into taking steps that might impact on actually informative features, like a PCA transformation, you're then potentially also directly impacting on predictive ability.
2. A minimum number of samples is needed per feature for models to effectively learn. By including redundant features, this sample:feature ratio is diminished, which makes it more difficult for many models to determine whether or not a feature is a useful predictor.
3. You make it more likely to overfit to the "noisy" features.

You can recursively reject features that the model's feature_importances_ routine has decided are unimportant using sklearns recursive feature elimination. Or, in the exploratory phase of building your model, you can assess predictive power using visualisation or hypothesis testing.

This nicely highlights the improvement in performance by ditching redundant features:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py

Answer (score 1):

In general, for random forests and boosting the regularization hyperparameters (mtry, max depth, colsample_byX, lambda, alpha and maybe gamma among others) are often sufficient enough such that explicit wrapper based feature selection often makes the model not perform any better or possibly even worse. Feature selection is a binary choice, either we leave a feature completely out or completely in the model. Through regularization, we include all variables but ideally only allow each one to influence predictions to the point where it is beneficial.

Wrapper based feature selection can still be useful, but usually for models that have very little regularization. Removing redundant features does improve computational speed which can in turn allow you to try more hyperparameters or more experimentation in other areas like feature engineering. However, it is not like wrapper based feature selection is blazingly fast either since you end up fitting hundreds of models and evaluating them to see if the feature selection method is working anyway. Furthermore, using feature importances properly such that you don't leak information and bias your test set scores is an expensive and honestly annoying task in itself (deriving the feature importances, and then evaluating say the top k features quickly becomes time consuming, albeit easily made parallel).

There are also business reasons for why you might do explicit wrapper based feature selection, ex: collecting variables that are not useful could be expensive. I think a case can be made to try wrapper based feature selection if you have the time and patience to do it properly (along with a decent amount of data to get consistent variable importance scores). Otherwise, it is not always necessary and might not even give any improvement especially if you are using newer ML algorithms that have large amounts of regularization already built in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into a situation right now where I'm removing features with literally 0.0% average importance (according to an ensemble of tree-based classifiers) and getting (slightly) worse cross-validation performance as a result. So there's no guarantee that performance will improve by removing unimportant features.